# Problems using html-to-image in a React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, wkhtmltoimage

I am trying to use html-to-image to create a downloadable image of a specific html card. In its documentation it specifies to use

```
var node = document.getElementById('my-node');
htmlToImage.toPng(node)...
```

But this works on real DOM and not in react. I tried using refs but its unfruitful. The card and the download button is in different branches in Component Hierarchy.

Comment: If  you past your Component, i could give you a hint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the new React Ref

```
    class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} />;
  }
}
```

In order to access the element, use:

```
const node = this.myRef.current;
```

Comment: can you please explain it more .